# Javascript pricing slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if someone could help with some Fiddle code, or an explanation of how to create a simple interactive JavaScript pricing slider.

What I'm after is a slider that goes from 50 to 500, going up in increments of 1 for the sider (so when you slide to the left or to the right, you get a single digit - 1, 2, 3 etc)

Number of employees

```
 -50---100---150---200---250---300---350---400---450---500

        <-----         |||         ----->
```

Price of software:

`[£2 per employee]`

I would also like to bind an additional £1 to the total cost if this check box is selected:

`Add £1 for this additional feature:
[x]`

^ This is a check box that will dynamically update the price with an additional `£1` for every added employee.

Can anyone help me with creating the JavaScript or direct me to a plugin for doing this please?

Here is a similar pricing chart: https://www.bamboohr.com/pricing.php

Comment: There are hundreds of jQuery controls like this, the most prolific of these is probably the jQueryUI one. Did you even Google?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200329/how-to-create-a-jquery-price-slider

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this jslider plugin http://egorkhmelev.github.io/jslider/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at jQuery UI slider (with rangemax, rangemin):
http://jqueryui.com/slider/#rangemax

See sample files for examples :)